# React Native build issues

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When i try to run assembleRelease command in react native, i get the following error,

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

and after this i get some android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon.png duplication error find the below image for more info..

> [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon] D:\User\rms\FincApp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon] D:\User\rms\FincApp\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
> [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\User\rms\FincApp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] D:\User\rms\FincApp\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

below is my gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties file
[image]

below is my gradle/gradle.properties file

```html
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=51
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.182.0
reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64
newArchEnabled=false
hermesEnabled=true
```

below is my package.json file

```html
{"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.0.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea I have had this issue as well, I modified a build script I use to remove the duplicates.  You can manually remove the duplicates by opening up Android Studio under the Res folder and delete the duplicated assets.

However, a cleaner approach would be to use something like running this in the terminal at the root of the project

```
cd android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf index.android.bundle && cd ../../../../ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && rm -r *DIRECTORY OF THE DUPLICATES FILES*
```

You can then add in the commands for assemble release either at the end of this script, or keep it separately.